# How do I correctly implement this switch statement to compose a string?

Tags: java, string, random, switch-statement

I want to produce a string that is a single letter (A, B or C), followed by two random numbers. I have written the following code:

```
enum ReportType {CHILD, ELDER, BOOMER};


    public String setNumber(Report.ReportType type) {

        Random rand = new Random();

        String number = String.valueOf(rand.nextInt(10)) + String.valueOf((rand.nextInt(10)));
               
              
        switch (type) {
            case CHILD:
                String prefix = "A";
                break;
            case ELDER:
                prefix = "B";
                break;
            case BOOMER:
                prefix = "C";
                break;
    

                 accountNumber = prefix + number;

        }
        return accountNumber;
    }
```

When I run the code I just get the two random numbers, without the prefix. I am unclear where the error is, but I am guessing I did something wrong with the switch statement.

Comment: Why have a switch at all? If you know `type` already, enrich your `enum` so that they have an associated String value, so you can just do `accountNumber = type.toString() + number`?

Comment: Your line `accountNumber = prefix + number;` is unreachable. Apart from that your switch cases are needlessly complicated. Just return directly from the cases like `case CHILD: return "A"+number;`

Comment: BTW, you can also generate a 2-digit random number with `String.format("%02d", rand.nextInt(100))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Immediate fix is shown here. But better solutions are shown in [Answer by Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66804216/642706).

- We expanded the scope of `prefix` by declaring *outside* your `switch` rather than *inside*.
- We moved the `accountNumber` assignment to *below* the `switch` rather than *inside*. In the old position, that line of code was never reached. The `break` command moves the flow-of-control past the entire `switch`.
- We declared `accountNumber` as a `String`.

```java
    enum ReportType {CHILD, ELDER, BOOMER};

    public String setNumber(Report.ReportType type) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        String number = String.valueOf(rand.nextInt(10)) + String.valueOf((rand.nextInt(10)));
               
        String prefix = "" ;   // Declare `prefix` here…
        switch (type) {
            case CHILD:
                prefix = "A";  // … not here.
                break;
            case ELDER:
                prefix = "B";
                break;
            case BOOMER:
                prefix = "C";
                break;
        }
        String accountNumber = prefix + number; // Declare and build `accountNumber here, not in the unreachable place within `switch` after last `break`.
    
        return accountNumber;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 12 introduced [switch expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/language/switch-expressions.html):

```
String prefix = switch (type) {
  case CHILD -> "A";
  case ELDER -> "B";
  case BOOMER -> "C";
};
String accountNumber = prefix + number;
```

The advantage of this is that the compiler checks to ensure you've covered all the cases.

For pre-Java 12, I'd use a method (*):

```
String getPrefix(Type type) {
  switch (type) {
    case CHILD: return "A";
    case ELDER: return "B";
    case BOOMER: return "C";
  }
  throw new AssertionError("Switch not exhaustive!");
}
```

Then:

```
String accountNumber = getPrefix(type) + number;
```

Of course, if you have control over the enum, you could add a method to the enum:

```
enum Type {
  CHILD("A"), ELDER("B"), BOOMER("C");

  private String prefix;

  Type(String prefix) {
    this.prefix = prefix;
  }

  String getPrefix() { return prefix; }
}
```

and then use it like:

```
String accountNumber = type.getPrefix() + number;
```

---

(*)
I write it like this rather than a default because I'm used to using
a compiler with [ErrorProne's MissingCasesInEnumSwitch check](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/MissingCasesInEnumSwitch) - the
switch is checked for exhaustiveness when there is no default.

Answer (score 0):

The statement accountNumber = number + prefix is never reached/executed. When the case happens, prefix is set, and then break statement causes the program to jump to the next line just after the closing switch curly bracket. You need to put it outside de switch block, so, after the decision of which prefix to set, the statement is always executed.

Answer (score -2):

You need to move the line `accoutNumber = prefix + number;` outside of the switch statement.

Comment: Then he would get the error that prefix is undefined because it is a local variable in the switch statement.

Comment: but at least this would solve the "Unreachable code" error  - and a step  in the correct direction